# How to use intent in non activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some little problem with android. Just wanted to know how to call intents from an Adapter Class which just extends BaseAdapter and not Activity Class.

Answer (score 28):

Simply you can use this,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class)
                      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

This code will call an activity from your base adapter class. And I don't know what you want to do..
But this will give you a hint

Answer (score 13):

To start an activity you need context. Try with the following approach

pass the context parameter to the constructor of the class which extends BaseAdapter.

### Example

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    }
```

To start an activity use the following approach

```
Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.abc.mypackage", "com.abc.mypackage.NewActivity");
        context.startActivity(i);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually custom adapters are inner classes of an `Activity` subclass. This means they a reference to an outer `Activity` in the `OuterActivity.this` field, where `OuterActivity` is the name of the activity, containing the adapter class . In this case you can start an `Intent` using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OuterActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
OuterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

In other case when the adapter class is not nested, you can pass a `Context` reference to its constructor like it's done in `ArrayAdapter`, `SimpleAdapter` and so on. You'll have to store this reference in a field and use it to start an intent. That's possible because you don't really need an activity to start an intent. Actually you need a context. Here's the example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // Other methods...

    private void startIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Sample{

//Declare context variable
    Context context;

//Constructor where the context is assigned.
    public sample(Context context){

        this.context=context;

    }
//Most functions that you'd find in a typical activity class come from the
//Context class. So to start something, use the class' context to start that intent
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,sample.class));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

```
//Declare mcontext

Context mContext 

//and where you need to execute code

Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Classyouwant.class)
                      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);      
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Intent i = new Intent(NAMEOFCURRENTACTIVTY.this,ANOTHERACTIVITY.class);
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

and don't forget to put name of that file into AndroidManifest.xml file inside the `<application></application>` tag

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<activity android:name=".YOURACTIVITYNAME" />
```

happy coding :):) Pragna

Comment: The question is for non activity class, your solution is for which will work for activity.